How Trigger Alarm with specified ringtone from mobile when firebase notification received in Flutter?
I working on Flutter app were my approach is to trigger Alarm when firebase notification received,
I done it using Alarm package [https://pub.dev/packages/alarm] but it works only when app is running or in background.
I also want to trigger alarm when app is terminated.
Please can anyone help me.
Thank you.
